How to control the random rotation angle of star glow in blender synthesis

This star glow looks too uniform, I wonder if there is any way to make them random, like random size, random angle, random transparency, which is confusing to me because I can't find a node that can control this


The objects are all the same in shape, size and brightness - why should there be random glow? In reality, the size and strength of a glow depends on size and strength of the light emitting object and on technical properties of the lens, sensor etc. taking the picture. Also the angle of star streaks are dependent on the techincal properties of the device capturing it. For example star streaks in Hubble telescope pictures are different from JWST pictures - but the angles are always the same for the same telescope. Variation in size and strength comes from brightness and size of the star.

@GordonBrinkmann: he wants it random...and he didn't write anything about realism ;) it is right what you are writing ...but in German school class we would say: Thema verfehlt ;)

@Chris Not really: as I said, in reality randomness is created by variation in the source objects and by variations in technical devices. This can be transferred to the Glare node as well (not for streak angles, but glow size and strength) - if he wants variation, he can get that by varying the size and brightness of the "stars". I did not ask, why don't you want how it is in reality, I opened with: they are all the same, why should the glow be random? At least (since there is no "randomness" setting as he already discovered) there is no source providing variation for the glow.

...and it would have been nice if the uploaded file would at least show the same result as the screenshot, but the glow there is completely different.
